# how to fetch position of the image inside the grid view?

Tags: android, gridview, imageview

I have a set of imageviews placed together in a row inside a grid view. If I am touching on an imageview in it and moving forward or backward through the image set, I should get which image I have touched right now(eg: its position in the grid view). How will I achieve it? Can anyone please help?

Comment: do you mean column number or x coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

The `position` parameter in your `onItemClick()` method is the `position`.

Comment: But that is when we use OnItemClickListener...I want to perform a continuous touch within these images...When we touch it will take only the image which I first touched...rest it wont take...thats the issue...